# keras: Smooth L1 loss

Tags: deep-learning, keras, loss-function

Try to customize loss function(smooth L1 loss) in keras like below

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 5 for 'cond/Switch' (op: 'Switch') with input shapes: [?,24,24,24,?], [?,24,24,24,?].

```
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np


def smooth_L1_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    THRESHOLD = K.variable(1.0)
    mae = K.abs(y_true-y_pred)
    flag = K.greater(mae, THRESHOLD)
    loss = K.mean(K.switch(flag, (mae - 0.5), K.pow(mae, 2)), axis=-1)
    return loss
```

Answer (score 11):

I know I'm two years late to the party, but if you are using tensorflow as keras backend you can use tensorflow's [Huber loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/huber_loss) (which is essentially the same) like so:

```
import tensorflow as tf


def smooth_L1_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.losses.huber_loss(y_true, y_pred)
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is an implementation of the Smooth L1 loss using keras.backend:

```
HUBER_DELTA = 0.5
def smoothL1(y_true, y_pred):
   x   = K.abs(y_true - y_pred)
   x   = K.switch(x < HUBER_DELTA, 0.5 * x ** 2, HUBER_DELTA * (x - 0.5 * HUBER_DELTA))
   return  K.sum(x)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. But I still got the error: **ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 5 for 'cond/Switch' (op: 'Switch') with input shapes: [?,24,24,24,?], [?,24,24,24,?].**

Comment: @yuanzhou That means the network output or your targets have wrong/incompatible shapes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it's the problem with the shape of output and targets, when I use other loss function, it works fine. The error occurred only using the customized smoothL1.

Answer (score 2):

```
def smoothL1(y_true, y_pred):
    x = K.abs(y_true - y_pred)
    if K._BACKEND == 'tensorflow':
        import tensorflow as tf
        x = tf.where(x < HUBER_DELTA, 0.5 * x ** 2, HUBER_DELTA * (x - 0.5 * HUBER_DELTA))
        return  K.sum(x)
```

Comment: if the backend is Tensorflow, you should you tf.where instead of K.switch